# mysql running scheduled event returns: Query is empty

Tags: mysql

Im trying to run a scheduled event, and getting an error: Query was empty.
Any ideas?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `event_test` (
 `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 event_name VARCHAR(100),
 event_time TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
); 

DELIMITER $$
CREATE
EVENT event_test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ENDS '2014-01-01 00:00.00'
DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO event_test (event_name) VALUES("TEST_EVENT");
END;
 DELIMITER $$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$$` as the statement terminator after `END`.

Edit by RolandoMySQLDBA

For the benefit of everyone else, Bill caught a typo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
EVENT event_test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ENDS '2014-01-01 00:00.00'
DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO event_test (event_name) VALUES("TEST_EVENT");
END;
 DELIMITER $$
```

it should be

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
EVENT event_test
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE ENDS '2014-01-01 00:00.00'
DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO event_test (event_name) VALUES("TEST_EVENT");
END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure scheduled events  is working by enabling [event-scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_event-scheduler) in `my.cnf`

Please add this to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
event-scheduler=1
```

You may not have to restart mysql. Login to mysql and run this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

See if the scheduled task kicks in. If it does not then run

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Also worthwhile advice, since this is a common hurdle for folks trying to use MySQL events!